# php call to oci_execute in try catch block

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    oci_execute($command);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    $this->sendMailFunction($e);
}
```

where `$command` is a Oracle SQL Query. My Question is, if the query fails, the control is not going into the catch block. Why is it so?
I am using yii framework of php.

Comment: Is oci_execute documented to raise exceptions?

Comment: exception is raising but control is not going into catch block.

Answer (score 3):

`oci_execute` doesn't throw Exceptions. If it fails, boolean `false` will be returned and a `Warning` will be generated. To get the error details you'll need to call the `oci_error()` function instead of `try/catch`:

```
if (false === oci_execute($command)) {
    $this->sendMailFunction(oci_error($command));
};
```

If you don't want the `Warning` in your error log you can prepend a `@` sign to suppress it.